# MySQL privilege - grant create view and select in the created views?

Tags: mysql

Recently I have issued the `grant create view` to a user, but it seems the same user cannot select those views that he has created. Why that happens? how can I grant create view and after, if the user create some view, he automatically get the privilege of select on it?

Comment: CAN this be useful? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html

Comment: the problem is after the user create a view, he can't select the view he created. I didn't find anything about it in the link.

Comment: The user needs select on the database.

Comment: Yes, I have granted select on whole database to the user, but I don't really agree with it because he should select only his views, but I didn't find anything that automatically give select privilege to himself in the view he has created.

Comment: I dont think that exists because views are created from others tables so you need access to everything on it.